# Tkinter based UI in yocto has only one font size

Tags: python, tkinter, yocto

I have a python 3 app with a TKInter interface. Very simple UI, there are 4 frames each with a headline (big text) and a status (small text). It works well on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.

```
fr = Frame(root, width=width / 2, height=height / 2, background='black')
self.headline_label = Label(fr, textvariable=self.headline, background='black', foreground='green', font=("Arial", 40))
self.stats_label = Label(fr, textvariable=self.stats, background='black', foreground='green', font=("Arial", 25))
self.headline_label.place(anchor=CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.3)
self.stats_label.place(anchor=CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.6)
column = int(position / 2)
fr.grid(column=column, row=position % 2)
```

Final deployment is a Raspberry Pi 3B, Official 7in LVDS display, Yocto Poky Dunfell. Base image is core-image-x11. My recipe is very minimal, add a user, install my python script, install python libraries it depends on, install config file for my python script (api token, etc) and install mini_x session script which auto-launches my script inside of matchbox-window-manager as the new user.

The problem is both the headline and the status label are the same size. I'm not sure either are the correct size. I have attempted to change the font sizes and the font name ("Mono", "Liberation", "LiberationMono-Regular") but it stays the same. I'm not picky about what font is used, it just need to be big enough to see from a few feet away.